HAProxy and Drupal containers reverse proxy issue
Trying on an EC2 instance
I am trying to accomplish 3 Drupal instances as Docker containers with HAProxy.
docker run --name c1 -p 8081:80 -d drupal
docker run --name c2 -p 8082:80 -d drupal
docker run --name c3 -p 8083:80 -d drupal

HAProxy.conf looks like this:
global
    log /dev/log local0
    maxconn 4096
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
defaults
    log global
    mode http
    option httplog
    timeout connect 5000ms
    timeout client 50000ms
    timeout server 50000ms
frontend http_front
    bind *:80
    stats uri /haproxy?stats
    acl url_c1 path_beg /c1
    acl url_c2 path_beg /c2
    acl url_c3 path_beg /c3
    use_backend c1_backend if url_c1
    use_backend c2_backend if url_c2
    use_backend c3_backend if url_c3
backend c1_backend
    server c1 127.0.0.1:8081 check
backend c2_backend
    server c2 127.0.0.1:8082 check
backend c3_backend
    server c3 127.0.0.1:8083 check’’’

When I try to hit http://EC2-IP/c1 it reroutes to http://EC2-IP/core/install.php. This gives 404 not found. Ideally it should be http://EC2-IP/c1/core/install.php should serve the request or that's what I believe it should be.
